# How to hide mouse pointer on scroll?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

One of the several features I enjoyed with Google Chrome for Chromebook was the mouse pointer would hide upon page scroll and only unhide if the mouse pointer was moved again with the mouse or trackpad.

This is not default behavior on Chrome for Windows 10, BUT the mouse pointer DOES hide when scrolling using the laptop's touchscreen.

How can I hide on mouse or trackpad scroll?